# What does the /sys/class/block/*/hidden file mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

Block devices(but not partitions) exposed to userspace through sysfs have a file called hidden, but it doesn't appear documented anywhere?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reflects the GENHD_FL_HIDDEN bit in the flags. The only place I can find this being set is in the drivers/nvme/host/multipath.c file, where the comment says

```
/*
 * If multipathing is enabled we need to always use the subsystem instance
 * number for numbering our devices to avoid conflicts between subsystems that
 * have multiple controllers and thus use the multipath-aware subsystem node
 * and those that have a single controller and use the controller node
 * directly.
 */
```

and the code sets the bit if multipathing is enabled for the nvme[0-9]c[0-9]d[0-9] name(s) but not for the nvme[0-9]n[0-9] name(s).